# OpenVR: failed to find interface ''IVRCompositor_027"

Tags: virtual-reality, openvr, steamvr

I cloned the openVR repo and went directly to compile the driver_sample and hellovr_dx12 and hellovr_opengl projects. The builds were successful. But both the helloVR applications failed to launch with an error:

```
Failed to find interface 'IVRCompositor_027'
```

I have no clue except My guess is that the variable `IVRCompositor_Version` might need to be set appropriately, but how to find the right version?

Using SteamVR 1.15.15 on Windows 10, VS2019.
The HMD (HTC Vive) is correctly setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated SteamVR to the lastest version and the issue is solved.

Comment: To clarify why that happen, openvr only got that interface with that particular version only in the last release, which was 1.16.8 and it got released on 02.25.2021, almost a month before this question. And so to clarify what happen is you updated openvr, not SteamVR